# Loading LOG FILE IN HIVE TABLE

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a requirement in hadoop where i need to load a set of log files into hive table and query on it.

The Sample Log file looks like ,

---

```
# Comment

# Comment

01 record1 record2 record3 record4

02 record1 record2 record3 record4

03 record1 record2 record3 record4

# Comment

# comment
```

I want to eliminate this # comment line which starts with # in each line.

The Actual content i want to load is space delimited and structured.

Any solution/suggestion about how to load the data by eliminating comment lines ?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the files using unix commands:

if the fields don't contain `#`, use grep -v '#' filename.log > stripped.log
else look on using the sed command 
sed '/^#/d' filename.log > stripped.log , this will remove all lines starting with #

For cleaning huge files UNIX commands are not recommenced. You should clean your data using a MapReduce program.

You can perform your cleaning operation on each line, and then insert it into a hive table for querying. PFA the map reduce program for cleaning the comments from data files.

**hadoop jar CleanData.jar HDFS data location HDFS Hive table folder Namenode host name:PortNo**

Sample map reduce program to clean data

```
public class CleanData {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,NullWritable> {


        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            NullWritable nullWritable = NullWritable.get();
            String line = value.toString();
            if(line.substring(0, 1).equals("#")){}
            else
            context.write(value,nullWritable);                  
        }   
    }






    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", args[2]);
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(CleanData.class);
        job.setJobName("wordcount");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);        

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify serde while creating the hive table.
 An inbuilt RegexSerde will serve your purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE regex_log_table (
  id STRING ,
  val1 STRING,
  val2 STRING,
  val3 STRING,
  val4 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "(^[0-9]+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)$",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

You can write a custom serde if you need more customized data loading.

Ref: http://shout.setfive.com/2013/12/10/hive-how-to-write-a-custom-serde-class/